# How can I populate custom UITableViewCell with JSON data?

Tags: uitableview, swift5, ios14

I've been practicing networking with swift 5, but I seem to always get stuck on parsing json to the UITableViewCells. I've looked at many tutorials, but can't seem to figure out the problem.
What I'm looking to do is retrieve the name of the country and place it in the tableview cells.

I use this url to request json: https://restcountries.eu/rest/v2/

The view models:

```
struct Countries: Codable {
    let name: String?
    let capital: String?
    let region: String?
    let population: String?
    let currencies: [Currency]?
    let languages: [Language]?
    let flag: URL?
}

struct Currency: Codable {
    let code: String?
    let name: String?
    let symbol: String?
}

struct Language: Codable {
    let name: String?
}
```

My API request:

```
class Service {
    static let shared = Service()
    
    func fetchCountriesData(completed: @escaping (Result<Countries, ErrorMessages>) -> Void) {
        
        let urlString = "https://restcountries.eu/rest/v2/"
        
        guard let url = URL(string: urlString) else { return }
        
        let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { (data, response, error) in
            // error
            if let _ = error {
                completed(.failure(.invalidData))
                return
            }
            
            // response
            guard let response = response as? HTTPURLResponse, response.statusCode == 200 else {
                completed(.failure(.invalidResponse))
                return
            }
            
            // data
            guard let data = data else {
                completed(.failure(.invalidData))
                return
            }
            
            do {
                let decoder = JSONDecoder()
                //decoder.keyDecodingStrategy = .convertFromSnakeCase
                let results = try decoder.decode(Countries.self, from: data)
                completed(.success(results))
            } catch {
                completed(.failure(.invalidData))
            }
        }
        task.resume()
    }
}
```

My MainViewController:

```
class MainViewController: UITableViewController {
    
    var cellId = "cellId"
    var countryData =  [Countries]()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
        style()
        tableView.delegate = self
        tableView.dataSource = self
    }
    func style() {
        navigationItem.title = "Search country information"
        tableView.register(CountryViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: cellId)
        //tableView.separatorStyle = .none
    }
}

extension MainViewController {
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        guard let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: cellId, for: indexPath) as? CountryViewCell else {
            return UITableViewCell()
        }
        let results = countryData[indexPath.row].name
        cell.titleLabel.text = results
        return cell
        
    }
}
```

And the custom TableViewCell:

```
class CountryViewCell: UITableViewCell {
    
    private var countryResults: Countries? {
        didSet {
            self.titleLabel.text = countryResults?.name
        }
    }
    
    var titleLabel: UILabel = {
        let label = UILabel()
        label.text = "countries"
        label.font = .boldSystemFont(ofSize: 16)
        label.numberOfLines = 0
        label.textColor = .black
        return label
    }()
    
    override init(style: UITableViewCell.CellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
        super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
        configure()
        layout()
        //displayResults()
        
    }
    
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
}

extension CountryViewCell {
    func configure() {
        selectionStyle = .gray
        titleLabel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    }
    func layout() {
        addSubview(titleLabel)
        
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            titleLabel.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: leadingAnchor, constant: 20),
            titleLabel.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 20),
            titleLabel.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: centerYAnchor),
        ])
    }
}
```

Comment: In the `JSONDecoder` scope `catch ` the `error` and `print` it. It tells you exactly what's wrong. Further don't declare any struct member carelessly as optional.

Comment: And never `guard let cell` in `cellForRow`. If an error occurs you will see nothing and have no idea why. Force unwrap the type. The possible error is a design error which can be fixed instantly.